# PhoneGap/ Cordova 9-patch Image Splash Screen with center Logo?

Tags: android, html, cordova, nine-patch

I use PhoneGap/Cordova to create an Android app with a splash screen that contains a centered logo.

Here is what I did:

In my Android Manifest.xml I added

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
```

Then I used the nine-path image generator [here](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) to create the 9-patch images for the splash screen. The purpose is to have a logo centered in the center all the time. When uploading the image it looks like the following. I kept the edit mode "stretch regions".

[image]

The problem is that the splash image is stretched all the time. This means that the logo (the blue box) is disproportioned.

I checked the solutions here [Cordova/PhoneGap 9-patch splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226207/cordova-phonegap-9-patch-splash-screen) but it did not help.

**How can I use 9-patch images as a splash screen on Android such that the logo is always in the center of the screen and not stretched?**

Comment: I've done a 9-patch splash screen and recipe is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27125893/3765109
Good luck!..

Comment: I managed to get mine to work with having only one file in drawable/splash.9.png It seems as if any other location and it just got picked up as a straight png which it stretched...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the area you have selected - the logo - is at the same time the area that will be used to stretch. You have to define different stretch areas that are outside of your logo's bounding box. While horizontal stretch area can be beneath or above your logo, vertical stretch area can be only left or right to your logo. So the image will never be in de center, as you want it. You have to use different tool to do this. [Check this page out](https://fsiete.blogspot.de/2013/10/android-9-patch-splash-screens-that-do.html)

Answer (score -1):

just try to build the apk  using the eclipse not in  cli I too had the same problem but when i build my app  using the eclipse the image did not streched just  try it out the following link can help u create a nine patch image http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/stretched_9_patch_splash_screens_android

Comment: Why part of the link should help there is a lot and a lot of sublinks?

Comment: it will  help  u create a nine patch image there is a image explained how you can create the image

Comment: Well, this is for PhoneGap build. How can I do it for normal PhoneGap / Cordova?

Comment: using cordova you cannot use a nine-patch image.It treats a nine-patch image as a png image only